# Dog acts afraid of me when we’re around other people?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, psychology, fear

I have an adopted 3 year old husky/lab mix.
He was very well trained when I adopted him, apparently he’d been a stray, but had two previous adopters who gave him up.
The reason being was they had young children and he’s very pawsy so being that I have no children nor do I plan on it, I adopted him.
He’s been great, only had a few accidents inside when I left him alone for too long due to work.

I recently had to get a roommate because covid reduced my income.
My roommates love the dog, but have been keeping him out of his kennel while home, which is fine, but when I come home he acts afraid of me and won’t listen to me anymore or anyone else and has began to jump and not listen and bark. So much to a point my roommates both stopped letting him out of his kennel until I get home, except to use the bathroom and won’t feed him, etc. because they saw the change in his behavior.

I’m curious how to curb the possible separation anxiety, but also not sure why he runs to roommates when I let him out of his kennel now once I come home and even jumps up on them while they’re on the couch and as soon as I come over, he pees.

We’re all very worried about this behavior and not sure why or what caused it.

Comment: Welcome to Pets. Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. Have you continued obedience training with him since you adopted him? Have you been sterner than before lately? Have you compared your own behavior with that of your roommates? You can [edit] your own question any time to add more information. In the meantime, please have a look at [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2979/12501) and let me know if it's the same situation as with your dog.

Comment: Did the dog act strange too, with groups of peoples before? Because it is a rescue one need to have in mind past situations, which could cause him stress now. Huskies are a breed with very strong pack-behavior, so I am not surprised, that the dog is happy to have a big pack (additional roommates). If Elmy's guess is right, then the dog is happy to see you again, and do not react to commands because of this outburst of feelings. What are the signs, that the dogs shows, that led you to the conclusion the dog is afraid?

Comment: Without more information it will be hard to decide which feelings cause the behavior of your dog